# ADT Bundle without certificate

Tags: google-play, adt

I have this problem: I export my application from Eclipse ADT Bundle, set up the key but when I try to upload it on Google Play it says the certificate is not valid. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide a little more detail.

Comment: Ok. I have this game I made in Eclipse. I'm using the latest Eclipse ADT Bundle from google server. I go to project->export, export android application -> create new keystore (fill the data) -> fill data for key information -> export apk. Then I go to google play app publish, upload the APK and I get the error that certificate is not valid.